# Grails: how to parse date.toString() without making a custom formatter?

Tags: date, grails, groovy

I have a Grails application that needs to parse Dates out of strings that were created with the date.toString() method.

My system's default date.toString() format is `"Thu Apr 20 00:27:00 CEST 2006"` so I know I can turn a Date into a string and then back into an object using `Date.parse('EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy', new Date().toString())`.

But that's lame!  I shouldn't have to reverse engineer the system's default date format.  Plus, I'm not sure under what circumstances the default date format can change, thus breaking that code.

Is there a way to parse a date.toString() back into a Date without using a hand-rolled formatter like that?

Thanks!

**Update:**  I filed [this Jira ticket](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4789) to get such a feature added Groovy.  Someone commented on the ticket that Java's date.toString() method is hard-coded to use EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy.  That sucks for Java to be so inflexible, but it makes it easier for me to live with hard-coding the formatter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [page over here](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/) showing how bad this is in Java (and hence in Groovy)

I agree that there should be a `Date.parse` method in Groovy which uses this default `Date.toString()` format.

Maybe it's worth adding a request for improvement over on the [Groovy JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY)?

As a temporary workaround, you could add your parse method to the `String metaClass` in `Bootstrap.groovy`?

```
String.metaClass.parseToStringDate = { Date.parse( 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy', delegate ) }
```

Then you can do:

```
new Date().toString().parseToStringDate()
```

anywhere in the groovy portions of your grails app

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I'll probably add a method to Date rather than String because it's a companion to date.toString()  If no one provides a full solution by tomorrow I'll mark this one as accepted.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe that Date.toString() hasn't yet been converted to use a DateFormat for its output!  I was assuming it was using something like DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG).toPattern() but I guess not... :(

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Grails and I know this is not the answer to your question, but as a workaround, couldn't you just save the format-string as a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

if u use it to convert to json, maybe code below could help:

```
//bootstrap
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Date) {
  return it?.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
}
```